# Plotting a number under the candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using version 5

I check whether indicator conditions are met, and if they are, I get a specific number - 1, 2 or 3.

I want to display these numbers under the candles.

I have this code, where I try to convert my numeric value to string with `str.tostring()`.

```
finalCountText = str.tostring(finalCount)
plotchar(finalCount,title="",text=finalCountText,location=location.belowbar)
```

However, I am getting this error in console:

> Cannot call 'plotchar' with argument 'text'='finalCountText'. An
> argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is
> expected

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the `plot*()` functions because your `finalCountText` won't be a constant, hence the error message.

You should use `label`s instead.

```
label.new(bar_index, low, finalCountText, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

I would also suggest you add `max_labels_count=500` to your `study/indicator/strategy` call.

Answer (score 0):

@vitruvius answer is the the preferred method IMHO, and I personally prefer it to the below solution, but if for some reason you prefer using `plotshape()` method instead of `label` you can set a condition inside the function. For example:

```
plotchar(finalCountText == "-1",title="",text="-1",location=location.belowbar)
plotchar(finalCountText ==  "1",title="",text="1" ,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar(finalCountText ==  "2",title="",text="2" ,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar(finalCountText ==  "3",title="",text="3" ,location=location.belowbar)
```

Again - `label` is much more flexible, and in most cases you won't need more than 500 of them, but if you need the `plotshape()` for any reason, that's the solution.